# Sublime Text not using build system specified in project settings

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've created a project JSON where I've also declared a build system to convert my markdown notes to pdf using pandoc. But each time I try to build a file Sublime Text uses another build system which isn't specified in the project settings JSON, which looks like this:

```
{
"folders":
[
    {
        "path": "Analysis I",
        "folder_exclude_patterns": [
           "docs"
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "Linear Algebra I",
        "folder_exclude_patterns": [
           "docs"
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "Computer Science",
        "folder_exclude_patterns": [
           "docs"
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "Physics I",
        "folder_exclude_patterns": [
           "docs"
        ]
    }
],
"settings":
   {
      "tab_size": 4
   },
"build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "Document Builder",
            "cmd": ["pandoc ${file_name} -o ${file_base_name}.pdf"],
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a selector. Try adding `"selector": "text.html.markdown"` so your build system entry. If that doesn't work, check the scope of the files you are using. You can do this by opening the ST console and running `view.run_command("show_scope_name")` in the ST console. There is also a key binding for the command, but I don't know what it is for every platform. Of course, you can look that up. In the default key bindings, search for `show_scope_name`.